# Brain Computer Interface Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I have a suggestion to make a *Brain Computer Interface* Stack Exchange. What is the requirement to do that?

Comment: I've never used the site but it might be on-topic at Cognitive Sciences, for example here's a related question: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/6554/is-eeg-brain-computer-interface-reliable

Comment: @PeterJ is correct, we would welcome your questions about BCIs on CogSci!

Answer (score 2):

For suggesting sites, use [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) (read the [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) to know how it works). First, do a search to check whether your proposal is already proposed. If that's not the case, then at the left sidebar, select the category for your proposed site (in this case, Technology). Scroll to the bottom and click "Propose a new Technology site", and fill in the form there to propose a site.